# Deployed web application is not accessible from other machines

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

I have deployed mvc application in IIS 7 on my machine(Windows 7 Professional).
Its working fine in my machine with url: http://localhost/testApp. When I tried to access the same (http://182.18.140.188/testApp) in other machines, I couldn't able to access. My system IP is 182.18.140.188.
I gave full permissions to other machines also. Still not working. Other machines are in same network and they could able to ping my machine. Please let me know how to access the application from other machines.

Comment: you enabled firewall permissions ? on which port are you using ?

Comment: By default, the port is 80

Comment: what message it showing when you accessing the application from different system ?

Comment: Now, I tried to access http://182.18.140.188/testApp in my machine, Its not working and showing error message:" Network Error (tcp_error)

A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time. "

Comment: was that worked previously ?

Comment: No.. Just now I deployed in my machine's IIS...

Comment: Have you enabled incoming access to port 80 for machines on your network in the Windows firewall settings? This will be **blocked** for incoming requests by default. Please provide more details of what you mean by "I gave full permissions to other machines also" - normally machine permissions on the files are not required, files will be read in the context of the application pool identity or local machine network service account depending on configuration in IIS.

Comment: @lavanyab Have you resolved your problem? If not - please can you help us by answering the questions regarding your computer's firewall.

Comment: @pwdst, problem is not yet solved. I have added Port 80 in Inbound rules of Firewall. But, no luck. "full permissions to other machines" means I gave full control permissions to other domain users.